# Xbox 360 hard disk doesn't show and it asks for additional USB flashdrive

Tags: xbox-360

I've bought a new Xbox 360 with a Hard Disk installed, but when I turn it on it asks me for a hard disk and asks for additional USB drives?

What's going on? Did they include the HDD in it or not?

Answer (score 4):

New Xbox 360s come with HDD drives disconnected. To connect it follow these steps:

1. Turn off the Xbox.
2. Press the hard disk switch near the vent and pull it out, it rotates out to reveal a hard disk slot.
3. If you have a HDD already inside, then remove it by pulling its leash and reinsert it tight.
4. Turn on the Xbox to have the HDD detect.